# Bash script for extracting function calls from c files

Tags: c, bash, awk, function-calls

I'm new to scripting, and I'm attempting to extract all function calls from a c files, all present in a directory. 
Here is my code so far, but it seems to be giving no output.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '/[ \t]*[a-zA-Z_]*\(([a-zA-Z_]*[ \t]*,?)*\);/ {print $0}' *.c
```

I'm stumped.
Also the c files all have at least one function call.

Comment: Because one does not simply parse C using regexes.

Comment: I think that gcc has options to tell you which are all the function call to external functions. Maybe this is what you really need?

Comment: I know I can use lex/yacc, but I'm trying out shell scripting with awk. Is there something wrong with using regex?

Comment: what to do for function calls that are commented out, left out with `defines`? what about handling prototypes? and macros that look like function calls?

Comment: All function *calls*? What for?

Comment: Your regex doesn't allow digits, or string literals, or nested function calls, or function calls inside expressions, or whitespace after `,` or `)`, or newlines inside function calls, or any of various other very common things. Though I admit, it's a bit surprising that you don't have even *one* function-call that passes all these hurdles . . .

Comment: I thought I'd first try all the simpler cases, and then tackle commented function calls, macros etc etc.

Comment: Got the error. It should have been escape sequence and then comma. \,

Comment: http://www.regex101.com/ try this site, put a few examples of function call, and try with your regex

Comment: Your code works for me (gawk v4.0.1). But as pointed out you will miss names and parameters that include more than just letter.

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your regexp. Reduce it until you get some matches, then add again the other parts, checking if you get the expected results.