# How can I parse C switch-case and for Statement in AWK?

Tags: c, parsing, for-loop, awk, switch-statement

How to parse switch-case statement like below with awk? I want to create simple C syntax checker with awk. This checker must read the code and return whether there is syntax error or not. If there is, awk should print what error on it.

```
switch(number)
{
    case 1  : number = 'a'; break;
    case 2  : number = 'b'; break;
    default : number = 'x'; 
}
```

And for **for()** statement, like this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) 
    {
        number = 'A';
    }
```

My current code for **switch-case** statement was:

```
#parser_switchcase.awk
{
for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
{
  if($i~/switch\([[:alnum:]]+\)/)
    print("switch(VALID_VARIABLE)")
}

}
```

result for my first C **switch-case** code above:

```
master@master:~/Dokumen/Root$ awk -f parser_switchcase.awk soalswitch 
switch(VALID_VARIABLE)
```

but really it needs many improvements. It is not complete.

I need awk suggestion just for reading and checking exactly code examples I have typed above. Exactly, so I just need awk parsing code for those, not the outside possibility such as additional function, additional code, only what mentioned on the codes above.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398732/bash-script-for-extracting-function-calls-from-c-files#comment25262143_17398732

Comment: I doubt awk is the right tool to do this...

Comment: Don't do this, just use an existing compiler.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to accomplish? What would be the output you would like to get for the above input? Then I might be able to help you even though I too do not see the point of this project (but I guess you have your reasons).

Comment: To get an idea of what it takes to parse a DSL in awk for a programming language, check out [awklisp](http://awk.info/?dsl/awklisp) and it's [source](http://code.google.com/p/lawker/source/browse/fridge/lib/awk/awklisp/awklisp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk for C syntax checks is a brave project.

I would use `gcc` for syntax checks. Try this:

```
gcc -fsyntax-only test.c
```

Comment: But I wanna create new compiler (of course simple, not as complex as gcc) for C. That is why I need awk suggestion. My need is not too strict, just what the above switch-case & for code appear.

Comment: I've not the expertise to craft a C compiler in awk, not even a simple one. But if you have that expertise it is possible, of course. Have you had a look into [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) before? I would use them.

Comment: For an important reason, I must use awk and not other. Okay, but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: maybe you should do it firstly with yacc and bison. Just to see how it works... Then, in the next step, create a tokenizer in awk that feeds another awk instance, the parser. this is how I would step into this

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, `awk` is not the right tool for this job...
But if you can guarantee that your code conforms to a fairly rigid and exact structure, such as the one presented in the question, you *could* write a very basic `awk` interpreter for it.

For example:

```
BEGIN {
  ERROR = "ERROR: ";
  WARNING = "WARNING: ";
}

# Start of switch statment
/switch/ { 
  # Cursory check for valid variable name: must start with a letter or underscore,
  # and be composed of alphanumeric characters or underscores.
  if ($0 !~ /switch\([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]*\)/)
    print ERROR "switch statement '" $0 "' has a syntax error.";

  switch_stmnt = 1;
  next;
}

# Start of for statement
/for/ {
  # For loop can have lots of various stuff between parentheses, so hard to check.
  # But, if you know it will always be `(i=0;i<10;i++)`, then it's much easier to 
  # create a rule.
  if ($0 !~ /for\(.*;.*;.*\)/)
    print ERROR "for statement '" $0 "' has a syntax error.";

  for_stmnt = 1;
  next;
}

# Start of case statement
/case/ { 
  # Check if in switch
  if (! switch_stmnt)
    print ERROR "case statement '" $0 "' outside of switch statement.";

  # Already in a case statement
  if (case_stmnt)
    print WARNING "case statement fall-through.";

  # Check syntax
  if ($2 !~ /[A-Za-z0-9_]+/ || $3 != ":")
    print ERROR "case statement '" $0 "' has a syntax error.";

  case_stmnt = 1;
}

# Default
/default/ {
  # Check if in switch
  if (! switch_stmnt)
    print ERROR "default statement '" $0 "' outside of switch statement.";

  # Already in a case statement
  if (case_stmnt)
    print WARNING "case statement fall-through.";
}

# Break
/break;/ {
  if (case_stmnt) { case_stmnt = 0; }
  else if (for_stmnt) { }
  else { print ERROR "'break' outside of case statement or for loop."; }
}

# Start of control structure
/{/ { ++brace; }

# End of control structure
/}/ {
  if (switch_stmnt) {
    switch_stmnt = 0;
    case_stmnt = 0;
  }
  else if (for_stmnt)
    for_stmnt = 0;

  if (brace == 0)
    print ERROR "Extra closing brace '}' with no matching open brace.";

  --brace;
}

{
  # Do syntax checking on regular lines, eg. "number = 'a';"
  next;
}

END {
  if (switch_stmnt || for_stmnt || brace)
    print ERROR "Unterminated for or switch statement at end of file.";
}
```

This checks that a few statements conform to a few rules. You can expand this with a lot more regex rules and flags. Especially difficult would be plain statements without keywords, since these could be declarations, assignments, function calls, etc. BUT, if you will only be making assignments such as `number = 'a';` as above, then it's also not too hard to match these lines (something like `/[A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]* = '.'/`)